# How can I use an Elascicsearch plugin in a JVM local node?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm in the process of adding support for unicode normalization in ES with the help of the [ICU analysis plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-analysis-icu). Installing this in a dedicated cluster is relatively easy, but I also need this plugin to be available during testing, where we use a JVM local node. Since it's a JVM local node I can't simply call the commands as explained in the [plugin documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-plugins.html). How can I get my plugin to work for this local node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the source code of Elasticsearch I figured out the answer, and it is stupidly simple: Just make sure the plugins are in your classpath and ES will pick them up automatically. In my case adding the plugin to my `pom.xml` was enough.